# Listing all the directories and all the files and uploading them to my bucket (S3 Amazon) with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Code below:

I'm using the findit walker, documentation here -> https://github.com/substack/node-findit

With this package i'm listing all the directories and files of my application, and i'm trying to send to my bucket on Amazon S3 (with my own code).

I'm not sure if the code is right, and i don't know what i need to put in the Body, inside the params object.

This part it's listening all the Directories of my app:

```
finder.on('directory', function (dir, stat, stop) {
    var base = path.basename(dir);
    if (base === '.git' || base === 'node_modules' || base === 'bower_components') {
        stop();
    }
    else {
        console.log(dir + '/');
    }
});
```

And this one it's listening all the files of my app:

```
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
  console.log(file);
});
```

I updated it to send data to my bucket, like this:

```
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
    console.log(file);
    var params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: file,
        //Body:
    };
    //console.log(params.body);


    s3.putObject(params, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
});
```

I really don't know what i need to put inside the Body, and i don't know if the code is right. Anyone could help me?

Thanks.

to help, all code, all the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var finder = require('findit')(process.argv[2] || '.');
var path = require('path');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new aws.S3();
aws.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
var BUCKET_NAME = 'test-dev-2';



finder.on('directory', function (dir, stat, stop) {
    var base = path.basename(dir);
    if (base === '.git' || base === 'node_modules' || base === 'bower_components') {
        stop();
    }
    else {
        console.log(dir + '/');
    }
});

finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
    console.log(file);
    var params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: file,
        //Body:
    };
    //console.log(params.body);


    s3.putObject(params, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    });
});

finder.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

finder.on('end', function () {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant parts of your code directly in to the question instead of posting an image of it. We can't do much with an image.

Comment: Sorry, I thought a picture of the whole code would be better, just a second @MikeS.

Comment: No problem. Often people will copy some or all of your code and try to reproduce the problem to determine what the best answer to your question is. That's not easy with an image :)

Comment: I think it looks better now @MikeS :D

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: if anyone answer, can i post again after 2 hours @MikeS?

Comment: You mean post the same question again? I wouldn't, you're likely to get down voted and your question closed pretty quick doing that. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62642/discussion-between-nescau-and-mike-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), the `Body` parameter of `s3.putObject` can take a `Buffer`, Typed Array, Blob, `String`, or `ReadableStream`. The best one of those to use in most cases would be a `ReadableString`. You can create a `ReadableString` from any file using the [`createReadStream()` function](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) in the `fs` module.

So, that part your code would look something like:

```
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
    console.log(file);
    var params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: file,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(file) // NOTE: You might need to adjust "file" so that it's either an absolute path, or relative to your code's directory.
    };

    s3.putObject(params, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
});
```

I also want to point out that you might run in to a problem with this code if you pass it a directory with a lot of files. `putObject` is an **asynchronous** function, which means it'll be called and then the code will move on to something else while it's doing its thing (ok, that's a gross simplification, but you can think of it that way). What that means in terms of this code is that you'll essentially be *uploading all the files it finds at the same time*; that's not good.

What I'd suggest is to use something like the [`async` module](https://github.com/caolan/async) to [queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) your file uploads so that only a few of them happen at a time.

Essentially you'd move the code you have in your `file` event handler to the queue's worker method, like so:

```
var async = require('async');

var uploadQueue = async.queue(function(file, callback) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: file,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(file) // NOTE: You might need to adjust "file" so that it's either an absolute path, or relative to your code's directory.
    };

    s3.putObject(params, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success!");
        }

        callback(err); // <-- Don't forget the callback call here so that the queue knows this item is done
    });
}, 2); // <-- This "2" is the maximum number of files to upload at once
```

*Note the `2` at the end there, that specifies your concurrency which, in this case, is how many files to upload at once.*

Then, your `file` event handler simply becomes:

```
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
    uploadQueue.push(file);
});
```

That will queue up all the files it finds and upload them 2 at a time until it goes through all of them.

Comment: Nah, just been doing this for a while ;)

Comment: Hei Mike, how the push is being used? I know the push method just to join arrays... haha.. UPDATED: NEVERMIND, I UNDERSTAND NOW haha

Comment: Day to day, not all that much at the moment (more focused on iOS development), but I've written quite a few web apps and utilities in node since mid-2011. If this is where you are after 3 months, you're doing fine :) As to `push`, it's just the function name `async` uses in this case (it's not the same `push` that's on arrays). It's named that way because things are usually "pushed" on to a queue (and "popped" off).

Answer (score 0):

An easier and arguably more efficient solution may be to just tar up the directory and upload that single tar file (also gzipped if you want). There are tar modules on npm, but you could also just spawn a child process for it too.